# Node-Red - How to disable configuration of nodes

Tags: node.js, node-red

I just got setup running node-red with everything as default. Currently, anyone could go into the node-red configuration web interface (http://localhost:1880) and change the nodes and how I have this configured. Is there an easy way to disable the web interface or implement a password so that I'm the only one able to access it?

I'd like to keep any other user to only have access to view the Node-Red server (http://localhost:1880/ui) but not access the configuration where they can make the changes.

Comment: Probably worth having a look at their docs about securing node-red: https://nodered.org/docs/security

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`node-red` lets you configure its admin interface, see https://nodered.org/docs/security .

Example of config to add in your `settings.js`

```
adminAuth: {
    type: "credentials",
    users: [{
        username: "admin",
        password: "$2a$08$zZWtXTja0fB1pzD4sHCMyOCMYz2Z6dNbM6tl8sJogENOMcxWV9DN.",
        permissions: "*"
    }]
}
```